# I'm trying to make a dropdown with a element inside li with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

First i'm gonna say i have 0 js knowledge i'm trying to piece it together from W3

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
                                <li class="dropbtn"> 
                                 <a onclick="myFunction()"  href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Smith <b <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></b></a>
                                  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                                </li>

                                
                                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">  
                                <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                    
                                
                                    
                                <li>
                                <a href="./backend/logout.backend.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                                </li>
                                    </div>
```

As you can see when i click on JohnSmith nothing happens but when i click on the button it works just fine

I want johnsmith to work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply account for child elements of the `.dropbtn` class to your JS function and you won't even need to add the class to any other HTML elements like your `<a>` or your `<button>`.

Just use `!event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .dropbtn *')` like this:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .dropbtn *')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<li class="dropbtn">
    <a onclick="myFunction()" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Smith <b><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></b></a>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</button>
</li>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="./backend/logout.backend.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: That works as well thank you so much i appreciate it.

Comment: @xMidNight-. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your class to the links as well.

So it would be :

```
<a onclick="myFunction()"  class="dropbtn" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Smith <b <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></b></a>
```

Comment: Works thank you so much <3 I'm such an idiot